# Is there a suffix that means "the science of...."

Tags: suffixes

I'm writing a fantasy book and I'm trying to come up with words to describe certain magic subjects and I want it to sound right.

Comment: 4 seconds with google, and https://www.quora.com/What-suffix-means-the-study-of

Comment: Yes, *-ology*, aka *the study of*. The study (science) of magic has been relatively firmly established as *thaumatology* in the genre of fantasy fiction, such as Pratchett’s *Discworld* cycle. But you may be seeking specific words for particular disciplines of magic (eg illusion, enchantment, summoning, etc) which would be hyponyms of *thaumatology* (also ending in *-ology*, as I said).

Comment: There's a suffix specific to divination, *-mancy*, e.g. necromancy. I think of divination as having some overlap with magic...

Comment: Which magic subjects? Are you looking for a general word for the science of magic (see earlier comments) or for words for the science/study of specific types of magic?

Comment: There's always "-ics" or "-onics":  Electronics, bionics, cryonics, harmonics, phonics, tectonics, et al.

Comment: I'm looking for a word to describe "the study of potions" specifically

Answer (score 1):

As answered in the comments, **-ology** [(dictionary.com)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ology) is the

> word-forming element indicating "branch of knowledge, science," now the usual form of -logy

To answer your real question, "the study of potions" is typically labeled **alchemy** in the gaming and science fiction/fantasy world.

[Skyrim](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy):

> Alchemy is the art of brewing potions and poisons by combining ingredients with matching effects, using an Alchemy Lab.

[World of Warcraft](https://www.wowhead.com/legion-alchemy-guide):

> Alchemists in Legion must rebuild the Dalaran Alchemy Table to craft their flasks, interesting elixirs, and cauldrons! This guide covers all of the World of Warcraft Legion Alchemy additions and changes, including Alchemy quests and new potions and flasks.

[Kingdom Come](https://www.ign.com/wikis/kingdom-come-deliverance/How_to_Learn_Alchemy_and_Brew_Potions):

> This page explains the basics of alchemy and brewing potions in Kingdom Come: Deliverance.

[Ultima Online](https://uo.com/wiki/ultima-online-wiki/skills/alchemy/alchemy-potions/):

> Alchemy Potions [table]

Comment: I did consider using "alchemy" because it appears in a few games. But then I looked up the actual definition and found that it specifically refers to making a Philosopher's stone so I didn't feel like it actually fit

Comment: Brits of a certain age think of Maureen Lipman when reading the title of this.